# PhpStorm Rebase my Github Fork - how to avoid multiple dialog windows

Tags: git, github, phpstorm

If the Upstream branch has several changes and I choose `VCS -> Git -> Rebase my Github Fork`, I get presented with the "Files Merged With Conflicts" dialog several times. Is there a way to tell it to wipeout my local changes and overwrite everything from Upstream?

I prefer a solution within PhpStorm, but I will also accept answers using git command line.

Answer (score 0):

If you want wipeout your local changes and overwrite everything from Upstream
you don't need to do a rebase.

you can do :

```
 git checkout -f
```

Comment: will that get latest from Upstream?

Comment: doesn't this command depend on which branch is currently selected?

Comment: I did...  C:\projects\myproj [develop ≡]> git checkout -f
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/develop'.
it doesn't get latest from the upstream branch.

Answer (score 0):

This method works for what I'm trying to do...

https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork/

I'll stop using the phpStorm "Rebase my Github Fork" command since I spent hours clicking Accept Theirs button over and over.

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).